# Best method to separate complex/multiple nouns and the verb? Semi-colon?

Tags: editing, punctuation, grammar

Would a semi-colon be appropriate separating a list of nouns all affected by a verb/or are all the agents responsible for said action? If not what do you all suggest without altering the structure of the example sentence below.

Ex: It was a period when the Blackhand of Nod's propaganda art targeting the middle-class, as well as rural women’s political, economic, and cultural agency; were rapidly developing, expanding, and intersecting under the exigency of war.

Note, the original semi-colon between "agency" and "were" was a comma.
Please help, I understand semi-colons may be "super commas" but I've been prone to use them with complicated sentences.

Answer (score 2):

### Semicolons can be used in place of periods or to build a list

When two or more sentences are very connected, sharing the same subject, and amplify the meaning or intensity of the previous sentence then you can use a semicolon instead of a period.  They must be complete sentences though, capable of standing alone.

### I like pie; however, cake is my favorite dessert.

The other use of semicolons is for lists that contain commas, as sort of a meta-comma or super comma.

I’ve shopped at used book stores in Fort Collins, Colorado; Denver, Colorado, and Tehran, Iran.